# Adafruit ADS1x15 library - I2C Bus error even though I2C is enabled

Tags: raspbian, python, adafruit

I am developing a program for a client using the Adafruit ADS1x15 library to use an ADS1115 module on the Raspberry Pi. This is the relevant part of the code where the error is occurring:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
```

Ther error occurs at the last line

The problem is that it is working normally on my Raspberry Pi, while it is giving an error on my client's RPi. I checked the settings on his RPi, and the I2C Bus is enabled there (which was causing the same error on my RPi, and it got fixed as soon as I enabled it).

The error:

[image]

It says "Could not determine default I2C bus for the platform.

Any idea why this is happening?
The script is running on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian Buster

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the Adafruit module doesn't know which I2C bus to use.

I suggest you look at the options to the `adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()` line and specify bus 1.

Have a look at the ADS1115 class definition in the Adafrut source file for the keyword to use.